# How to Sync Time with Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, clock-synchronization

I am getting lots of problems with the AWS API and Cloudberry Explorer. For example, on Cloudberry explorer I get:

> Your computer clocks are not synchronized. For security reasons Amazon
>   generates errors when your clocks are not synchronize. Check out
>   http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/ to sync your clocks.

I have not idea how to solve this. Can you please tell me the steps I need to do in order to kee the clock on my laptop sync with those of Amazon.

I've contacted Blackberry and they pointed me to a page that doesn't explain how to do it. I am stuck. Need your help on this. Thanks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon will check the time of the request to be within 5 minutes of actual time as one of the methods of signature verification.

All you need to do is make sure your laptop clock is accurate. All systems now have a way to keep the clock synced to a network time server. All you need to do is enable that, which is often is by default.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to do this on your pc? Then follow these steps:

1. Open Date and Time in Control Panel.
2. Click the Internet Time tab. The Internet Time tab is not available if your computer is a member of a domain.
3. Select the Automatically synchronize with an Internet time server check box.
4. In the Server list, click the arrow, and then click the time server you want to use.